# Operate pixel 3a XL without a battery

Tags: battery, power-options, google-pixel-3a-xl

I’m wondering if anyone out there who owns a **Pixel 3a XL** has ever tried to operate it without the battery.

I'm asking *specifically* about this model of phone, and am not looking for general guidance like "it depends on the phone".

I own a Pixel 3a XL and the battery has started to fail and has expanded as many lithium ion batteries will when they reach their end of life.

I’m using it in an always on situation (which perhaps hastened the battery failure), and I don’t really need a battery as it will always have an external power supply when in use.

Will it work if I remove the battery? Or is there any modification that I can do to get it to work in Android or via the hardware rather than installing a brand new battery?

I wanted to ask the community before attempting battery removal, since as described in this ifixit guide: https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Google+Pixel+3a+XL+Battery+Replacement/124631 it is quite involved.

TIA.

Comment: You could try it and tell us.  Some devices will work, others will not.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. We have an existing Q&A about the same issue, please take a look. Based on my experience with Google Nexus 5, it won't power on without the battery even if it's plugged in, so you may highly possibly need to follow the workaround hacks.

Comment: @RohitGupta unfortunately it requires many steps to disassemble the phone and remove the battery. I was hoping to not spend the time doing so if someone already knows it won't work.

Comment: Hi @AndrewT. I can appreciate that for those models listed, it doesn't work. So the odds are perhaps against it working for a Pixel 3a XL. But I want to know about this exact phone before I try and do a teardown to remove the battery if I can.